# jquery mobile datebox shows NaN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, datebox

I have used jquery mobile datebox [[http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox]](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox%5d) in our mobile site with ASP.NET MVC 4.

When I open datebox without setting default value, it shows "NaN" in date, month and year textbox.

I have written following code to show datebox.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ControlValue, "{0:d}", new { @readonly = "true", @type = "date", data_role = "datebox",  data_options = "{\"mode\":\"datebox\",\"overrideDateFormat\":\"%m/%d/%Y\",\"useNewStyle\":true}" })
```

And following bundle is also added in my view:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dateboxJs").Include("~/Scripts/jqm-datebox.core.js", 
            "~/Scripts/jqm-datebox_002.js", "~/Scripts/jqm-datebox_004.js", 
            "~/Scripts/jqm-datebox-1.1.0.mode.slidebox.js",
            "~/Scripts/jjquery.mobile.datebox.i8n.en.js"));
```

Not able to get it why is it happening?

Please help, if anyone knows or if anything I am missing.

Thanks in advance.